# Recuperando reCAPTCHA em aplicação Delphi

Tags: delphi, nfe, recaptcha

Tenho uma aplicação em Delphi que recupero do site da Fazenda o reCAPTCHA (não sou robô) para poder fazer o download da XML da nota fiscal eletrônica, porém em alguns computadores quando abro o formulário o sistema para de funcionar, como posso resolver esse problema?

Comment: "*Para de funcionar*". Podes explicar melhor? Da algum erro ou apenas trava?